# How to implement MVC like this in Python?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, sqlalchemy, metaprogramming, metaclass

For example, I have a config file named rule1.conf like this:

```
[Basis]
user = "sunhf"
time = "2012-12-31"

[Bowtie]
path = "/usr/bin/bowtie"
index = "/mnt/Storage/sync/hg19"
```

And a models.py like this(using a package named `magic.py`..):

```
from magic import Section
class Conf:
    __confname__ = None
    basis = Section(["user", "time"])
    bowtie = Section(["path", "index"])
```

At last, a viewer.py like this:

```
from models import Conf as my_conf
my_conf.__confname__ = "rule1.conf"  // bind to the config file, I have no ideas how to do this
print my_conf.basis.user    // output: `sunhf`
print my_conf.bowtie.index  // output: `/mnt/Storage/sync/hg19`
```

When I run `viewer.py` in command line:

```
$ python viewer.py
sunhf
/mnt/Storage/sync/hg19
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how to implement the `magic.py`?
Thanks!

Comment: It strikes me as weird that you'd want to work with the class itself rather than an instance of it in your viewer.py. Shouldn't you rather have a Conf.__init__(confname) which lets you create a configuration instance with a specific configuration file?

Comment: @vicvicvic In SQLAlchemy, I remembered that classes in `models.py` are just used for declaring and there's no need to make instance of them: http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html.

Comment: @vicvicvic And in my opinion, the `Conf` classes will only have one instance (Singleton), would it possible that I use the `Conf` class directly in `viewer.py` instead of use its instance?

Comment: I disagree with your understanding of how SQLAlchemy works. You do have to create instances of your model classes, e.g. you do `u = User("Firegun", "fire@gun.com")` when you use them. A singleton is when you only have one instance of a class, but here you're using the class itself as an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my solution here:

https://github.com/hanfeisun/meta_model

Use

```
python  test.py
```

to see the result